# R - using aggregate on several variables and combine unique values

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, unique

Suppose I have a dataframe cars, and the first several lines are:

```
Brand         Type         Year
BMW           Compact      2009
BMW           Sedan        2010
BENZ          Sedan        2010
BENZ          Compact      2012
BMW           Compact      2008
BENZ          Sedan        2011
```

I want to use aggregate to first find each combination of variable "Brand" and "Type", and then find the unique number of years of each combination. For example, the desired output is like:

```
Brand        Type         num_unique_years
BMW          Compact      2(which are 2009, 2008)
BMW          Sedan        1(2010)
Benz         Compact      1(2012)
Benz         Sedan        2(2010,2011)
```

The steps are basically this:

```
x <- subset(cars, Brand == "bmw" & Type == "compact")
length(unique(x$Year))
which gives me the output 2
```

However, I don't know how to combine these individual steps in one function.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the appropriate aggregation function and use `aggregate`.   No packages are used.

```
len_years <- function(years) {
  u <- unique(sort(years))
  paste0(length(u), "(", toString(u), ")")
}
Ag <- aggregate(Year ~., cars, len_years)
names(Ag)[3] <- "num_unique_years"
```

giving:

```
> Ag
  Brand    Type num_unique_years
1  BENZ Compact          1(2012)
2   BMW Compact    2(2008, 2009)
3  BENZ   Sedan    2(2010, 2011)
4   BMW   Sedan          1(2010)
```

**variations**

**1)** If you don't need the years themselves then replace the function with

```
len_years <- function(years) length(unique(years))
```

**2)** Alternately, replace the `aggregate` statement and the next statement with:

```
Ag <- aggregate(data.frame(num_unique_years = cars[[3]]), cars[-3], len_years)
```

**Note:**  The input `cars` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "Brand         Type         Year
BMW           Compact      2009
BMW           Sedan        2010
BENZ          Sedan        2010
BENZ          Compact      2012
BMW           Compact      2008
BENZ          Sedan        2011"
cars <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. I still got few question. 1. what is the use of sort in the function len_years? 2. if i want a new variable num_unique_yrs to replace Year in your output, how should I do that?

Comment: Also, when you use Year ~. in aggregate(), does this mean that the last function len_years takes argument from the variables Brand and Type, which are after ~. ? Sorry for so many questions..

Comment: One last question, if I just want those rows whose num_unique_years is greater than 1, then should I edit the last line of len_years with u[length(u) > 1]?

Comment: So if I want those with length > 1, there is no way to achieve this in one line?

Comment: `subset(aggregate(...), num_unique_years > 1)` using the variation (1) in the answer.  If you want you can even write out the function within the `aggregate`.

Answer (score 1):

I can do it in 2 steps with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(brand = c("BMW", "BMW", "BENZ", "BENZ", "BMW", "BENZ"),
                 type = c("Compact", "Sedan", "Sedan", "Compact", "Compact", "Sedan"),
                 year = c(2009, 2010, 2010, 2012, 2008, 2011))


dt[ , num_unique_years := length(unique(year)), by = .(brand, type)]
unique(dt[, .(type, brand, num_unique_years)])
```

The final result:

```
      type brand num_unique_years
1: Compact   BMW                2
2:   Sedan   BMW                1
3:   Sedan  BENZ                2
4: Compact  BENZ                1
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I noticed that you used data.table here, but what if I want a data.frame, will it have the same result? Also, I'm still thinking about doing it in one step using aggregate. But thanks very much for your brilliant idea

Comment: The other answer will fit your needs. I didn't end up figuring out how to do it in one step - I'm still learning too!

Answer (score 0):

How about using dplyr:

`library(dplyr)
count(group_by(count(group_by(cars,Brand,Type, Year)),Brand,Type))`